# DAX - Finding complete Backorders

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have this very complex database, from which I'm trying to figure out which orders in status 'backorder' or complete and should be shipped.
To get those ordernumbers that I search for, the following is (as simple as possible to me) what I need:
for every ordernumber in orders
where orders.status = 'backorder'
order_rows.aantal < 0 and order_rows.returned = 'YES'
and
order_rows.aantal > 0 and stock.location in 'Backorder', 'Sent'

I hope this makes it possible to start with answering my questing.
The screenshot is available both as xlsx or as pbix file. Just don't know how to upload in this question.
[image]

Comment: I don't understand why you say to use ordernumber from the orders table but in the visualization you are using Ordersnumber from the stock table. In the absence of the data model and based on the annotation on the productcolor-price table and the presence of a products table, the following is based on a supposed bridge table (orders) between the stock and order_row tables. To facilitate the help I uploaded the data present in the image. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HgyYJmEld4lO-tmjB1P3HU0hr0jSfJ5L/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Filter on this visual: CompleteBackOrders is 1 
CompleteBackOrders := 
VAR SLocation = COUNTROWS(FILTER(VALUES(stock[Location]),stock[Location] IN {"BACKORDER", "SENT"}))
VAR OR_QTY = COUNTROWS(FILTER(VALUES(order_rows[qty_order]),order_rows[qty_order] IN {-1}))
VAR O_BackOrders = COUNTROWS(FILTER(VALUES(orders[status]),orders[status] IN {"BACKORDER"}))
RETURN
IF(SLocation>0 && OR_QTY>0 && O_BackOrders>0 ,1 ,0)

Comment: It seems impossible for anything to match your filter as you wrote in pseudocode? You wrote "order_rows.aantal > 0 and ... order_rows.aantal < 0". As every comparison is "and", those two clauses will exclude every row.

Comment: I'll pretend you didn't say anything and explain how it works. The measure provided would work based on the assumptions made in my previous comments, since for me the question has incomplete information. I repeat, in my personal opinion.
SLocation scans if the column stock[Location] filtered by orders[ordernumber] present in the visualization contains "BackOrders" or "Sent", OR_QTY scans if the column order_rows[qty_orders] filtered by orders[orderumber] present in the visualization contains { -1}, the same process is fulfilled in O_BackOrders for its respective condition.

Comment: Finally those three conditions are compared, a 1 or 0 is returned that can easily be changed by text or used within the table. Cheers and good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I will look into your solution in the next few days.

Comment: @jprzd - in case you were offended by my comment, let me clarify that it was not referring to your code but the pseudocode written by the OP Ekfa.

Comment: @MikeHoney: as I stated it's a complex question in relation to the tables which are in the database. With what you call 'the pseudocode' I solely tried to simplefy the question. It's not meant as a true and working code of any kind.

Comment: @jprzd - Your code is starting to get to an answer I'm looking for. In the example-data it comes up with the one ordernumber I highlighted. But as soon as the qty_order is changed for example to -2 it doesn't work anymore.
What I wanted to work is that as soon as the qty_order is a negative number, the code should work. Our customers can sent more than 2 in returnshipments. The code also should check if the value for 'returned' has been set to 'YES', to see if the returnproducts are actually been received by us.

Comment: @jprzd - Only when that is true, it should check if the other order_rows belonging to an ordernumber (based on order_id) are set to 'backorder' or 'sent' in the stock-table by the same ordernumber. So when qty_order says 4, the ean of that order_row should appear 4 times in the stock-table with a 'backorder' or 'sent' location, belonging to the ordernumber.